# Simple subquery in Esper

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I want to be able to nest queries expressed in Esper's EPL. Let's assume I want to detect this pattern: `A -> (B -> C)`. (`A`, `B` and `C` are types of events, `->` is EPL's sequence operator.)

Here is the query representing `B -> C`:

```
select * from pattern [every (b=B -> c=C)]
```

I would then like to do the following:

```
select * from pattern [every (a=A -> bc=
    (select * from pattern [every (b=B -> c=C)])
)]
```

Actually, it would be best if something like this would be possible:

```
select * from pattern [every (b=B -> c=C)]) as bc
select * from pattern [every (a=A -> bc)]
```

This way, the first query is just bound to an identifier `bc`, which can then be used in the second query. That would be awesome!

Could someone please tell me if similar syntax exists in EPL? I appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query could simply be...

```
every (a=A -> (every (b=B -> c=C))]
```

Or insert "bc" into another stream and use that...

```
insert into BCStream select * from pattern[every b=B -> c=C]; // also note lack of parens
```

and

```
select * from pattern[a=A -> BCStream]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain why you "lacked" the parentheses, though?